# Eager loading inside appending property in model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I want to append `category_id` into `seat` collection, but I need to fill it using eager loading or relation.

where am I doing wrong?

Seat Model:

```
class Seat extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $appends = ['category_id'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'seat_name',
        'seat_url',
        'logo_src',
    ];

    public function getCategoryIdAttribute()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AdSeatCategories::class);
    }

}
```

when I run `Seat::all();`, I get `{}` for `category_id` in response.
response example:

```
{
"id": 95,
"seat_name": "gtest",
"seat_url": "http://ooop.com",
"logo_src": null,
"category_id": {},
},
```

Comment: Firstly, you are defining a `relationship` within an `accessor`, these need to be separate. Secondly, your relationship shows that the `seat` can have many `categories`. Is your relationship `one to one` or `one to many`?

Comment: It is important to know your intended relationship as this will determine if you are to return an array of categories or a single category id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `getCategoryIdAttribute()` is returning a relation, when you instead want it to return the collection so be sure to call `get()` like this:

```
public function getCategoryIdAttribute()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AdSeatCategories::class)->get();
}
```

Alternatively, perhaps instead you want a relation and an attribute:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AdSeatCategories::class);
}

public function getCategoryIdsAttribute()
{
    return $this->categories()->get()->pluck('id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate a relation from an attribute eager loading.

```
class Seat extends Model
{
   public $appends = ['category_id'];

   /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $fillable = [
        'seat_name',
        'seat_url',
        'logo_src',
    ];

    public function getCategoryIdAttribute()
    {
        return $this->categories()->pluck('id');
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AdSeatCategories::class);
    }

}
```

a better solution using the relation `categories` would be in the call of the model `Seat`.

```
class Seat extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $fillable = [
        'seat_name',
        'seat_url',
        'logo_src',
    ];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AdSeatCategories::class);
    }

}
```

in the controller do:

```
$seats = Seat::with('categories:id')->get();
```